# How to force tab to fit to small space in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As per doc, I tried fullWidth, centered for tabs, Does not seem to work. How do force tabs to re-adjust to given screen size ?

I am using latest beta v23[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a working reproduction of this behavior on codesandbox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the easiest way to force the tabs to fit a smaller container width, would be:

`<Tab style={{ minWidth: 50 }} label="item" />`

The default minimums are 160px for medium-and-up, 72px for small-and-down screen sizes.

Depending on how small the fit should be, you can also do other kinds of overrides on padding and font. [I tried out a few techniques on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5pym4714o).

Remember, the more we compact the tabs, the worse usability. There should be other workarounds too! For instance, shortening the label texts, using icons, or restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

I came here when I was looking for how to make the width of the tabs relative to the contained text. So here how i solved it acording to previous answer.

```
items.map((item) => (
<Tab
  style={{ 
    minWidth: `${item.title.length}` + `em`,
    paddingInline:'2em'
  }}
/>
))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is nearly four years old) with an existing, upvoted answer. Why is this better than what has already been suggested?